# How can I add line break to json output

Tags: php, json, ajax

Below is the ajax part. Which is returning a single line like this:

> appleorangebanana

What I would like to achieve is:

> - apple
> - orange
> - banana

as clickable links. Sorry I am still new with ajax & json. Thanks for looking into my enquiry.

```
    <div class="col-md-4" id="testing">

    </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $(".nav > a").click(function(e){ // see change here
            e.preventDefault();   
            $.post("test.php", 
                {
                    value:$(this).text().trim()
                }, 
                function(data) 
                {

                    $("#testing").html(data.replace(/\"/g,""));//to remove quotes from the output

                }
            );

        });

    });
```

**data.php**

```
<?php require('../config/connection.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['value'])){

    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT product FROM prdct_categories WHERE class =   '$value'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $rowvalue = $row['product'];

        echo json_encode($rowvalue);

    }       

}
?>
```

Comment: When you `json_encode('something')` the resulting string will also be `something`. And to display it in a newline in html you will need to also echo a html line break after echoing the value.

Comment: Where do i add the <br/> tag here ?

Comment: Right after the `echo json_encode(...`, although I don't think you need the `json_encode()` function.

Comment: I believe you could use this:
       echo json_encode($rowvalue)."<br>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may (or may not, depending on your application) be easier to build the entire HTML in your backend and feed it straight into your JS AJAX call. Assuming you're willing to take this path, you can do something like this in your backend script:

```
// You MUST take care of a possible SQL injection! 
// There can be ANYTHING in the $value.
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT product FROM prdct_categories WHERE class = '". mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

// Let's build a nice unordered list out of this.
$html = '<ul>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $clickable_url = ''; // something meaningful must be here, of course.
    $html .= '<li>';
    $html .= '<a href="'. $clickable_url .'">'. $row['product'] .'</a>';
    $html .= '</li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
echo $html;
```

And in your AJAX frontend, it's simply adding this new HTML to your DOM:

```
$.post("test.php", 
    {
        value:$(this).text().trim()
    }, 
    function(data) 
    {
        $("#testing").html(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey this is what I was looking for